# How can I decrypt password of HG8145V5 PPPoE?

Tags: decryption, router

I want to convert my ISP given router from route WAN to bridge WAN mode and they are using PPPoE connection. I also have backup of configuration and its file name is "hw_ctree.xml".

I was snooping in the file, and I found `Password="$2e&quot;:m~l*&quot;24WthjTTyL3Fca1@(%U&gt;QV=Yh[,}s@!=$"` line in the block of `WANPPPConnectionInstance`.

Comment: Password="$2e&quot;:m~l*&quot;24WthjTTyL3Fca1@(%U&gt;QV=Yh[,}s@!=$"
Password=123456

Comment: Password="$2e":m~l*"24WthjTTyL3Fca1@(%U>QV=Yh[,}s@!=$" Password=123456
how did you get this result?

Answer (score 3):

You need to edit the router's XML config, find this XML tag and edit your hashed password as below.

```
<PreSharedKey NumberOfInstances="1">
<PreSharedKeyInstance InstanceID="1" PreSharedKey="$2e&quot;:m~l*&quot;24WthjTTyL3Fca1@(%U&gt;QV=Yh[,}s@!=$" KeyPassphrase="" AssociatedDeviceMACAddress=""/>
</PreSharedKey>
```

now login to the router and locate your wifi setting
your plain password will be the wifi password