# How to decrypt PPPoE password of Huawei HG8245W5-6T?

Tags: decryption

Can someone help me to decrypt the PPPoE password from a Huawei HG8245W5-6T fiber optic ont.
The password has this format: `"$2lT_)L2t{NViWZSYEt@&quot;/qwP82OAN)&lt;s+mv~AVu[&quot;$"`

I tried to decrypt it with the *Huawei configuration encryption and decryption tools* but no luck.
I need to put the Huawei in bridge mode but the internet provider won't provide the credentials.

Comment: https://reverseengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/31024/how-can-i-decrypt-password-of-hg8145v5-pppoe?rq=1 ? Older models also seem to have JTAG and serial. Could be helpful if the rest fails.

Answer (score 1):

This is a free tool for deciphering such passwords:
https://andreluis034.github.io/huawei-utility-page/#cipher