# decrypt pppoe password of huawei ONT HG8145V5 ROUTER

Tags: router

Hi my ISP is not providing me the PPPOE password but i need them urgently in the confrigation file the password is encrypted Password="$2A;L6(Lcj/Y"YG(-gG]@3Z!QHYZ-kQ[AyTQ}<zrK$" please help me to decrypt the password

Comment: Possible duplicate of https://reverseengineering.stackexchange.com/q/31663/1848