# Huawei Router EG8145V5 PPPoE Password Decryption

Tags: decryption

I want to know my PPPoE password but my IPS refuses to tell me. I went to the setup page and did inspect element and changed the type=password to text and found my password, but it is encrypted form. One more people had the same problem in this thread:[Decrypt PPPoE password of Huawei ONT HG8145V5](https://reverseengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/31663/decrypt-pppoe-password-of-huawei-ont-hg8145v5) and some people have managed to decrypt the hash. I want anyone of you to do it for me as it will really be helpful and please share the method too. I have 3 routers so I'm listing the encrypted passwords below:

Pass 1: 0b706edc0063b11a22bcd03666df374631883f5b0dedf7359124da2c350b0e6b

Pass 2: f29ce726c6955677c72989e2f8f38e25e4330af689832e7529876e13d1bda44c

Pass 2: bc2980257e3bb86818b64ef88cc0084e3556842a5c5106efe6031b09bb86fac4

Comment: Have you tried following the instructions in the link you posted? Looks like you just need to download a config file and copy/paste the value into the password utility page.

Comment: I didn't understand anything, I just want a method to convert that hash into password. Please help me get it

Comment: In the linked post, they said they logged in to the "ONT user interface" and "tried downloading the configuration file and inspecting the PPPoE section". Can you see anything like that?